# Collecting page data .TypeError: styled.div is not a function

Tags: next.js, styled-components, vite

I am using Vite to build a package, but when I use the package in Next.js, I get this error:

> Collecting page data .TypeError: styled.div is not a function
> at file: dist/org-chart-maker.mjs:3:29
> at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)

I can use `styled-components` in the Next.js project, but for some reason, Next.js sees the imported `styled-components` in my package as `undefined`.

I assume the problem is in my configuration?

`vite.config.ts`:

```ts
import { resolve as pathResolve } from 'node:path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import tsConfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';
import reactPlugin from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { peerDependencies } from './package.json';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    tsConfigPaths(),
    svgr({
      exportAsDefault: true,
    }),
    reactPlugin({
      jsxRuntime: 'classic',
    }),
  ],
  root: pathResolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  publicDir: pathResolve(__dirname, 'public'),
  build: {
    outDir: pathResolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    emptyOutDir: true,
    copyPublicDir: false,
    sourcemap: true,
    minify: false,
    target: ['esnext'],
    lib: {
      entry: pathResolve(__dirname, 'src', 'index.ts'),
      formats: ['es', 'cjs'],
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [...Object.keys(peerDependencies)],
      output: {
        interop: 'auto',
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          'react-dom': 'ReactDOM',
          'styled-components': 'styled',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Component:

```ts
import styled from 'styled-components';
const StyledDiv = styled.div``;
const Test = () => <StyledDiv>hello</StyledDiv>;
export default Test;
```

Output as `org-chart-maker.js`:

```js
"use strict";
const React = require("react");
const styled = require("styled-components");
const _interopDefault = (e) => e && e.__esModule ? e : { default: e };
const React__default = /* @__PURE__ */ _interopDefault(React);
const styled__default = /* @__PURE__ */ _interopDefault(styled);
const StyledDiv = styled__default.default.div``;
const Test = () => /* @__PURE__ */ React__default.default.createElement(StyledDiv, null, "hello");
module.exports = Test;
//# sourceMappingURL=org-chart-maker.js.map
```

Output as `org-chart-maker.mjs`:

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
const StyledDiv = styled.div``;
const Test = () => /* @__PURE__ */ React.createElement(StyledDiv, null, "hello");
export {
  Test as default
};
//# sourceMappingURL=org-chart-maker.mjs.map
```

Comment: As for Next.js configuration I have followed the guide from: 
https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#nextjs

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be:

> For some reason NextJS does not correctly interpret files, when they are ending with .mjs

https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/4438#issuecomment-1296908287

The fix was to set `build.lib.filename` to:

```
(format) => `org-chart-maker.${format}.js`
```